# Finding the origin of a calculation before it got sorted?

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I wanted to find the sum of each row and then sort it. I managed to do this but to make it more complicated I decided to find from which row the `min sum` and the `max sum` was originated.

Example: The row with the `min sum` is the 3rd and the row with the `max sum` is is the 5th.

The main issue in my approach that I attempted was that the b[] array (in the `sortfunction` below) which I used to store the initial `sum` of each row is now replaced with the sorted values and I cannot work with the unsorted values which would show the rows that are needed.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 3

void printnumbers(int arr[][COLS]);
void sortfunction(int arr[][COLS]);
int main() {
    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {{1, 2, 3},
                     {2, 3, 4},
                     {3, 1, 1},
                     {5, 5, 6},
                     {35, 335, 6}};
    printnumbers(arr);
    sortfunction(arr);

    return 0;
}


void printnumbers(int arr[][COLS]){

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j<COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}




//swap function below
void swap(int* xp, int* yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}


// sort function
void sortfunction(int arr[][COLS]) {
    int i, j, total, k, b[ROWS];
    k = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        total = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            total += arr[i][j];
        }


        if (j == COLS) {    
            b[k] = total;
            k += 1;
        }


    }
    for (k = 0; k < ROWS; k++) {
        printf("the sum of the %dst row is %d\n", k + 1, b[k]);
    }
    int a, q, min_idx;


    int n = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
    for (q = 0; q < n - 1; q++) {

        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        min_idx = q;
        for (a = q + 1; a < n; a++)
            if (b[a] < b[min_idx])
                min_idx = a;

        // Swap the found minimum element
        // with the first element
        swap(&b[min_idx], &b[q]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
        printf("\n");

//Now I want to find which row has the least sum and which has the max sum but the b[] array is already sorted.
    }
```

This prints:

```
the sum of the 1st row is 6
the sum of the 2st row is 9
the sum of the 3st row is 5
the sum of the 4st row is 16
the sum of the 5st row is 376

5 6 9 16 376 //it got sorted
```

and it needs to print also this:

```
The row with the min sum is in the 3rd row
The row with the max sum us un the 5th row.
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this is about. Can you tell us what it prints and what you want it to print?

Comment: Updated with what you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to make `b` an array of a struct with the sum and row numbers. The `swap()` and `sortfunction()` functions would then be as follows (including some minor simplifications):

```
typedef struct
{
    int sum;
    int row;
} tRowSum;

//swap function below
void swap(tRowSum* xp, tRowSum* yp)
{
    tRowSum temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}


// sort function
void sortfunction(int arr[][COLS]) {
    int i, j, total;
    tRowSum b[ROWS];
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        total = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            total += arr[i][j];
        }

        b[i].sum = total;
        b[i].row = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        printf("the sum of the %dst row is %d\n", i + 1, b[i].sum);
    }
    int a, q, min_idx;

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
    for (q = 0; q < ROWS - 1; q++) {

        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        min_idx = q;
        for (a = q + 1; a < ROWS; a++)
            if (b[a].sum < b[min_idx].sum)
                min_idx = a;

        // Swap the found minimum element
        // with the first element
        swap(&b[min_idx], &b[q]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        printf("%d (%d)", b[i].sum, b[i].row);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

After sorting `b` with respect to the sum, the original row numbers are then available for each entry.

Comment: Can you place it in the original code because I cannot fully comprehend what changes this might need.

Comment: @user17850871 I have updated the answer with the revised functions.

Comment: Now to find the min and max using the b[i].row, I will have to sort it again and take the first and last for the min max respectively?

Comment: @user17850871 It should not be necessary to sort the array again. With the `b` array sorted as above, the min/max sum are in b[0].sum and b[ROWS-1].sum respectively and the original row number of the min/max sum is b[0].row and b[ROWS-1].row respectively.

Comment: Yes I did this a few minutes ago as you just wrote it. All clear.thanks